# Twig: how to get the form model object in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i have create a new FormType, it have a value transformation from view->norm->model and back, all works fine! but inside my FormType-Template i need the model-object, so i try this one:

```
{% set media = form.vars.data %}
```

but this object is the "norm" representation and not the model. ofcourse, i just can use the "norm.model_property" to get my model, but i thougt that the model is already in a specific field inside the form object? how can a access the model direct via form object? or should i pass it by my own into the template ?

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $media = $event->getData();
    // "$media" is already my model object, how 
    // can i pass this object to the twig template ?
});
```

greez & thx,
  sky...

Comment: I am not sure if i even understand your question, what you are trying to do? are you trying to render a form field or what?

Comment: yes, i create a new FormType and try to render this with a custom template. and the question is, how can i get directly the model object? beware, i have a Model and a View Transformer: view->norm->model->norm->view... but if i try to get the data via "{% set media = form.vars.data %}" i get only the "norm" object... so i want direct the model object?

Comment: Wondering why you want to add the model object in the view. If you have whatever kind of logic don't put in in the view/template. Did you think about create a form_type extension ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Comment: i know, it is a little bit confused, but my FormType has 2 elements: "file" and "checkbox"... a "file" FormType need a "file-object" but i havnt this in my model, so i have to put "null", btw it makes no sense to fill a "file" TypeForm...